# Create Gradient on Top Right of the page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, gradient

Hy everyone,

I need to know, how can I create gradient on top right of the page like this picture?

[image: pic1]

I tried with this code, but it's still not working for me:

```dart
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: Alignment.center,
              stops: [
                0.01,
                0.3,
                0.4,
              ],
              colors: [
                Color(0xff2DBA61),
                Colors.yellow,
                Colors.white,
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

here is the result

[image: pic2]

Thank you. any kind of help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think you can make that by using the `CustomPaint`.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your `Scaffold` inside a `DecoratedBox` or a `Container` and set its `backgroundColor` property to `Colors.transparent`.

### Code sample

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topRight,
          end: Alignment.center,
          stops: [0.01, 0.3, 0.4],
          colors: [
            Color(0xff2DBA61),
            Colors.yellow,
            Colors.white,
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          leading: const BackButton(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Result

[image]

[Try the full example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=90f80f7f5b91c2010adc693103fbc56b)